# SQL Developer - can't create DB objects in mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle-sql-developer

I have SQL Developer Version 19.2.1.247 on Debian Linux, with Java version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14 (I know, not supported, but it seems to work), and JDBC installed from mysql-connector-java_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_all.deb.

I have connected successfully to mysql (Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)) and can see the system databases with their tables and an empty test database I created for this purpose. However, when I right-click on 'Tables' under any of the databases, I don't see any options for creating a table. I haven't found any information about whether this simply isn't implemented yet, and one would hope that with MySQL now being an Oracle product, this would work. But does it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a MySQL table using the `mysql` CLI or MySQL Workbench and **then** checked if you can see it (after a refresh/reconnect)?

Comment: Can you run a `create table' command in the SQL Developer worksheet?

Comment: @Vérace Yes, that works fine - I can see my tables and everything else, if they already exist.

Comment: @MichaelKutz No - the problem seems to be that I can't actually select a database. At least, if the database is empty, then I get an error: 'No database selected', whereas if there are tables, nothing seems to happen at all.

Comment: From the Mysql Command prompt, USE test; press enter, then SHOW TABLES; to see if your table is there.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I know, but thank you for commenting. I know how to do things in mysql, but I can't get SQL Developer to work as expected.

Comment: SQL Developer or MySQL Developer?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Oracle SQL Developer - sorry, I didn't know there was a MySQL Developer

Comment: MySQL Workbench (free) might be a better tool than Oracle SQL Developer to work with your MySQL database.  There likely is NO MySQL Developer tool (free).

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've been in contact with Oracle, and they confirm that it isn't supposed to work with SQL Developer; it is only meant as a help to migrate to Oracle's own DB. Shame, really - I don't think the workbench is as nice.

Comment: Open new question if we can help.  This one is way beyond one question/one answer.